# Understand error : Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: react-native, error-handling, components

I have this error and I don't understand where it came from.
I'm trying to set up a screen where I scan products and when it's done, I redirect to another page.
Could you help me identify the problem and why it behaves like this?

the error is :

> Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a
> different component.

My Code :

```
class Scan extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Press: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      reference: '',
      displayArray: []
    };
  }

   initListData = async () => {
    let list = await getProducts(1);
   
    if (list) {
      this.setState({
        displayArray: list,
      });      
    }
  };

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();

        if (parseInt(this.state.reference) > 0) {
      
      let product_data = await getProductByRef(this.state.reference);
      console.log(this.state.reference);
        if (product_data && product_data.reference_id && parseInt(product_data.reference_id) > 0) {                
          this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {reference : parseInt(this.state.displayArray.reference)})
        } else {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
      }
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
  }
};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync(); 
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _onPress_Scan = () => {
    this.setState({
      Press: true
    });
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ Press: false, scanned: true, lastScannedUrl: data });
  };

  renderBarcodeReader = () => {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.request")}</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.noaccess")}</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
        }}
      >
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ flex:1, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
        />
        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
          />
        )}
        <Button 
        color="#F78400" 
        title= {i18n.t("scan.details")}  
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {reference : parseInt(this.state.displayArray.reference)})}>{i18n.t("scan.details")}              
      </Button>     
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned, Press } = this.state;
    let marker = null;

  console.log('displayArray', this.state.displayArray, 'reference', this.state.displayArray.reference)
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={{flex:1}}> 
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} >
            {Press ? (
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {this.renderBarcodeReader()}
              </View>
            ) : (
                <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
               <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this._onPress_Scan}
              activeOpacity={3}
            >
              <Text style={styles.viewDetails}>Scan BarCode</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Scan;
```

[image: screen capture]

Comment: It'd be good to check all of the error trace, because this error normally points to a line in the component. Have you checked it, where does it point to?

Comment: thanks for your answer and trying to help me. I just edited my post to show you the screen capture af the emulator but I don't find it really helpful...

Comment: Enable debugging in Google Chrome and then be sure to open all of the call stack, you will be able to find it normally.

Comment: the problem comes from  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() when I delete it to test, the screen works. But I need the function it contains... I'm a little lost

Comment: Don't worry, we'll solve this :) What happens for you if you move this fn inside `componentDidMount`?

Comment: That's really nie of you : I get 'await' is only allowed within async functions

Comment: I'm seeing you already have an async for the componentWillMount, put `async` in front of componentDidMount and try again please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. When I do that I get "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method."

Comment: Can you create a sandbox with this code? Your error happens when you're trying to set state on an already unmounted component, so gotta check why your component is unmounted.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer. I don't know how to do a sandbox (I'm so sorry, really trying to learn)